# Object to ArrayList causes NullPointException

Tags: java, class

I just return to Java after few years, and I have a problem in traning app.

I want to add Book to class Library and I wrote that code:

```
public class Book{
    String author;
    String title;
    String code;
    int num;
    int num2;

    public Book(String author, String title, String code, int num, int num2) {
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.code = code;
        this.num= num;
        this.num2= num2;
    }
```

Library:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Library{
    ArrayList<Book> books;

    public void AddBook(String a, String b, String c, int ab, int ac) {
        books.add(new Book(a,b,c,ab,ac));
            }

    public void showBooks(){
        System.out.println(books);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Library l1 = new Library();
        l1.AddBook("Adad", "dasdasd", "asdasdasdas", 2121, 31);
        l1.showBooks();
    }
}
```

But I got NullPointException. It point line with AddBook method from Library class. 
I can't figure out it, even after research. I think it's a trival error, but I can't see it. 
Can someone who see my error, explain me what I wrote wrong?

Comment: This does not compile. You declare a variable `l1` and the use `b1` (wherever that came from).

Comment: @MuratKaragöz no, I saw this, I read this but in my example it was't helpfull

Comment: You never initialize `books`, so it is `null`, so it throws a NPE when you dereference it when calling `books.add(...)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you never initialized your arraylist. Try this:

```
public class Library{
ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();

public void AddBook(String a, String b, String c, int ab, int ac) {
    books.add(new Book(a,b,c,ab,ac));
}

public void showBooks(){
    System.out.println(books);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Library l1 = new Library();
    l1.AddBook("Adad", "dasdasd", "asdasdasdas", 2121, 31);
    l1.showBooks();
}
}
```

And better practice is to code against the interface. So change this line:

```
List<Books> books = new ArrayList<>();
```

And also lowercase the first letter of the method to `addBook(...)`

Comment: Damn! Right, thank U! Sometimes fresh look change everything ! :)

Comment: of course, but ur too fast, and I need to wait 10 min :D